# adding >> after li, except for last li

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, bourbon, neat

I'm developing a breadcrumb like this:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="behandelingen.html">Behandelingen</a></li>
    <li><a href="behandelingen-cat.html">Gelaatsverzorgingen</a></li>
    <li class="active">Environ Discovery</li>
 </div>
```

I'm styling the breadcrumb using Sass:

```
.breadcrumb {
  @include outer-container;
  @include shift(4);
  margin-top: em(50);
  padding-left: em(14);
  li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
}
```

to add a ">>" after every list item, I added this inside my li definition:

```
&:after{
  content: ">>";
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

this works fine, but now I want to add a rule that defines not to add a ">>" to the last list item. I tried this:

```
&:after:not(li:last) {
  content: ">>";
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

but that makes all ">>" disappear.

Can someone tell me how I can add a ">>" after every list item, except for the last one ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want `:not(:last-child)` instead:

```
&:not(:last-child):after {
  content: ">>";
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

`:last` is not a valid CSS selector, and you cannot have more than one simple selector within `:not()`. The `li` portion can be omitted since your nested selector already uses `li`.

`:after`, being a pseudo-element, also needs to be placed after `:not()` for it to be valid.